# LOGSTASH - Filter JSON

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I need to save only the contents of the ship node in a Kafka topic, unfortunately I have already performed several tests and the filter is not working

My json is similar to that

```
 {
  "_index": "abd",
  "type" : "doc",
  "_source":{
  "response_body": {
      "ship":[
    {
      "type"  : "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-8888"
    },
     {
      "type"  : "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-4444"
    }
            ]
  }}}
```

My logstash is configured like this

```
input {

  file {
     path => "${PWD}/logstash_input"
     start_position => "beginning"
     sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
     type => "json"
   }
}

filter{
    json{
        source => "message"
        target => "_source.response_body"
    }

}
output {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
    codec => json{}
    topic_id =>  "testtopic"
  }
```

Comment: Is the example JSON a document from elasticsearch, or is that what logstash is receiving?

Comment: @Texugo  I will need to consume the Elasticsearch doc